# display certain column values depending on other column value

Tags: sql

Let's say table called `Tb` has this columns `Checked`, `Cost1`, `Cost2`.

I do want to create a sql query which has to display one column: `Cost1` if `checked` and `Cost2` if `!checked`.

The `checked` value can be `0` or `1`.

I assume I can use the `case` condition, but how can I achieve this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have two columns?  `Checked` and `Cost` and then `SELECT Cost FROM TB WHERE Checked = 1`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Cost1 could be normal Cost and Cost2 Discount cost, and check tell you which one use.

Comment: @Juan - would be the same with two columns surely?  Change the SQL example I gave to give a Checked value of 0 and it will give the discount cost.  Wouldn't having two columns for cost break the first normal form of eliminating duplicate columns from the same table - two cost columns?  If the discount price is a percentage of the total price then this can be stored in a separate table as a discount percentage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right. A `case` expression will do.

```
select case when checked = 1 then cost1 else cost2 end as cost
  from Tb
```

Comment: @jarlh Wodering what is the difference? [**Here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) I see they use both `CASE expression` and `CASE statement evaluates`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza. A case expression is a part of e.g. a select, and has a "return value". Case statements can be used in stored procedures for conditional execution of code.

Comment: @jarlh Just wondering because english isnt my first lenguaje. So `select` is the statement and `case` is the expresion? Or in this example case is an expresion, but inside a storeprocedure can be a single statement?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, a SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE statement can contain a case expression. Inside a stored prodecure you can have case statements, to chose which code to execute depending on conditions.